# SQL Query getting not results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Select statement that gets the items based on the greatest date. it works but these are selected value from asp.net controls and one of the controls is a multiselect listbox  [image]

as you can see DynamicAtrributeID 937766 is show one time:
[image]

I need it to show all the rows that were in 937766 as well as the other rows which could be just one row. Is this possible

```
SELECT     VotingValueDynamicId, 
             DecisionValueID, 
             DynamicAttributeID, 
             VotingValue, 
             DecisionSurveyID, 
             VALUEDATEUPDATED, 
             RECORDSTATUS, 

FROM         Adjudicate.ONCOLOGY_DynamicDecisionValuesForCaseManager AS a
WHERE     (VALUEDATEUPDATED =
                          (SELECT     MAX(VALUEDATEUPDATED) AS Expr1
                            FROM        Adjudicate.ONCOLOGY_DynamicDecisionValuesForCaseManager AS b
                            WHERE      (a.DecisionValueID = DecisionValueID) AND a.DynamicAttributeID = DynamicAttributeID) ) AND (RECORDSTATUS <> 'D')
```

Comment: What type and version of SQL?

Comment: Looks like all your `MAX(VALUEDATEUPDATED)` rows have `RECORDSTATUS = 'D'` (or null).

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... You should always tag your SQL questions with the DBMS you are using and want an answer for.

Comment: It's SQL  2012 (11.0.2100.60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example shown, all the rows with DynamicAtrributeID = 937766 have different values on VALUEDATEUPDATED, so the query is showing one row for that DynamicAtrributeID because that's what you're doing, filtering and getting only the row wich has the max VALUEDATEUPDATED.
In other words, you can't get more than one row for a DynamicAtrributeID if you're filtering by his max(VALUEDATEUPDATED).

Answer (score 0):

As @necoflecap1 said , the issue is your filter condition, For VALUEDATEUPDATED , you are filtering max(VALUEDATEUPDATED) which any way going to give 1 value per DynamicAttributeID and DecisionValueID combination,since your filter in subquery is

```
    WHERE      (a.DecisionValueID = DecisionValueID) AND (a.DynamicAttributeID = 
    DynamicAttributeID)
```

I can see two possibilities here , either add one more filter for VotingValue column

```
    WHERE      (a.DecisionValueID = DecisionValueID) AND (a.DynamicAttributeID = 
    DynamicAttributeID) and (a.VotingValue=b.VotingValue)
```

or Do a

```
    group By VotingValue
```

inside filter subquery for max(VALUEDATEUPDATED) so that aggregation will perform  for every VotingValue (which is the column I can see coming with a different value for  DynamicAtrributeID 937766)